# How to iterate through lines in MRJob

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I have a text document full of lines of tweets that I need to run a MapReduce job on. I am using Python and MRJob to do so with the following code:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re
import datetime

class exerciseOne(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        fields = line.split(";")
        epochtemp = int(fields[0])
        difference = epochtemp/1000.0
        key = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(difference).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        yield(key, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exerciseOne.run()
```

A small sample of the text that needs to be analysed is contained here: https://textuploader.com/dnx59 if anyone is interested.

The issue I am having is I don't know how to iterate through the lines in the mapper method to generate all the key-value pairs. I have tried the following:

```
for line in lines
```

and

`while(line)`

but neither have worked for the dataset I am using. How can I correctly loop through these?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with this library but I think the pattern you are looking for is this:

Instantiate class:

```
line_mapper = exerciseOne()
key_generator = line_mapper.mapper(None, text_blob)
```

Where `text_blob` is the block of text you've linked too. You'll then be able to iterate over the `key_generator` object using a for loop for example